# Can't use class with external jars in gwt on server side

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, gwt, orientdb

At the beginning I had an error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.` I solved this problem by adding jars to `\war\WEB-INF\lib` folder. But then I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient` error while applying to database. This is the server code:

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    GreetingService {

public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    RegBugs rb = new RegBugs();
    String a = rb.getDbAdres();

    try {
        //The error is here
        ArrayList<String>  table = rb.getAllGitRecords();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return a;
}
```

Compilation is finished successfully. And when I start to call to server I get `An error occurred while attempting to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again.` from gwt. How could I solve this problem?

P.S. I use eclipse and gwt-plugin for it

The error occurs when I try to interrupt with orient database.

Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:108)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:53)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:127)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:53)
at ru.sersem.testgwt.server.RegBugs.getBugRecordsCount(RegBugs.java:192)
at ru.sersem.testgwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 40 more
```

Comment: You are using GAE runtime with GWT .. GAE has its own storage and you cannot use third party database with it. Either use GAE storage or deploy to regular Java environment.

Comment: Thanks. So what should I do to deploy gwt with regular Java environment?

Comment: Just remove GAE from the project options and proceed as you do with normal web applications. When you run on server, choose whatever server you like, Tomcat, Glassfish, ... etc.

Comment: That's so sad. Are you sure about this GAE storage?

Comment: Yes I am sure .. but if you like GAE and want to use it, there is Objectify project which makes it really easy and simple to use the data store. much much less pain than JDO or JPA. I use it all the time. https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/